# Python making a file as a folder

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a recursive file structure, but when I try to create a file, it creates the first folder but no further folders.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import shutil
import os

ext = [".html", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif", ".jpg"]

def findLinks( url, newPath ):
    resp=urllib2.urlopen(url) #open first link
    if resp.getcode() == 200:
        if "text/html" in resp.headers["content-type"]:
            s = BeautifulSoup(resp.read(), "html.parser")
            links = s.find_all( 'a' ) #put all a links into links list
            for link in links:
                f = link['href']
                print f
                newDir = newPath+f
                if not os.path.isdir(newDir): #if doesn't already exist
                    if not newDir.endswith(tuple(ext)): #if nota file
                        os.makedirs(newDir) # create all directories
                    if newDir.endswith(".html"):
                        newFile = open(newDir, 'w+')
                        newFile.write("sample text")
                        newFile.close()
            return links

findLinks('http://localhost/onlinecontent/Test', '/Test' )
```

Comment: What links are present in `http://localhost/onlinecontent/Test`? What is being created? What do you *expect* to be created?

Comment: What is the `print f` line giving you? What do you mean by *the first dir*, only one directory is being created or only the first directory in a path with several dirs deep? You should consider using `os.path.join` instead of `newDir = newPath+f`.

Comment: Gil, there are files within this directory, and further folders with more files. I expect these folders to be created, and the files to be.also created. Memoselyk - only the first directory in q path with several dirs deep is being create. Thanks for the tip on joining 